# Command line move file with long directory path without repeating directory path

Tags: command-line

Is there any way of executing a `mv` command without typing the full path in the second argument?

Example:

`mv my/file/that/has/a/really/long/path/foo.bar some_magic_operator_that_means_the_same_directory/foo.baz`

Comment: Any reason you can't just `cd` to the directory and `mv` from there?

Comment: I frequently find myself executing these kinds of commands across multiple directories in my day to day work. I often need to execute several commands from a given parent directory.

Comment: Somehow I found that using !! (double exclamation signs) in a terminal uses to run the last command executed. You can also add parameters/text to the last command but never tried to change/remove text from the last command. Try it and if you succeed I will drop this like an answer. Good luck!

Comment: Remember that after `cd` to whatever path you can then `cd -` to go back instantly.

Answer (score 40):

You can use bash's brace expansion. This:

```
mv my/file/that/has/a/really/long/path/foo.{bar,baz}
```

will expand into:

```
mv my/file/that/has/a/really/long/path/foo.bar my/file/that/has/a/really/long/path/foo.baz
```

and then `mv` is run with those two arguments. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace for more on brace expansion.

Comment: That's glorious. I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to brace expansion, you could use the bash shell's *history expansion* features:

- `!` introduces a history expansion
- `#` event designator denoting the current command
- `$` word designator referring to the last argument

You can perform substitutions on the expansion using a sed-like `s/pattern/replacement` syntax e.g.

```
somecommand path/to/foo.bar !#$:s/.bar/.baz
```

Ex.

```
$ mv -v somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/foo.bar !#$:s/.bar/.baz
mv -v somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/foo.bar somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/foo.baz
'somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/foo.bar' -> 'somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/foo.baz'
```

If you want the path specifically (for example, to `mv` a file to a completely different name that is not easily obtained by substitution), you can use the `h` modifier:

```
$ mv -v somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/foo.baz !#$:h/baz.foo
mv -v somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/foo.baz somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/baz.foo
'somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/foo.baz' -> 'somepath/Original/Dir3/SubDir1/baz.foo'
```

For other options, including `readline` key combinations to yank the last argument, see [How to repeat currently typed in parameter on bash console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40128/how-to-repeat-currently-typed-in-parameter-on-bash-console)

Answer (score 3):

### With a variable

1. Save the directory in a variable : `` `DIR=./really/long/path/ ``
2. use move : `mv "$DIR"foo.bar "$DIR"foo.bz`

In one line : `DIR=./really/long/path/; mv "$DIR"foo.bar "$DIR"foo.bz`

---

### Changing directory

1. You could also `cd` to the directory you want to work in : `cd ./really/long/path`
2. then change the file name : `mv foo.bar foo.bz`

In one line : `cd ./really/long/path && mv foo.bar foo.bz`

Comment: that second one looks familiar ;-)

Comment: Best use `&&` in that last one-liner. Otherwise, if the `cd` fails, the `mv` will be run in the wrong directory, potentially overwriting a file. With `cd ./really/long/path && mv foo.bar foo.baz`, `mv` will only be run if `cd` succeeds in changing directory.

Answer (score 3):

You might try:

```
pushd .
cd /really/long/directory/name/
mv whatever.1 whatever.2
popd
```

Comment: Use instead: `cd /really/long/dir/name/; mv what.1 what.2; cd -`

Answer (score -3):

You can you alias command to short the directory name:

```
alias src='/directory/name/of/source'
alias dst='/directory/name/of/destination'
mv src dst
```

Comment: -1 `alias test='/var/log' ; cd test` gives `-bash: cd: test: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Did you test this and when under which circumstances does it work then? Aliasing is used to replace commands afaik not args. Although the !#$ solution would be more elegant in any way....